# Error while inserting into an AVL tree

Tags: c++, avl-tree

I am getting an error while doing insertion in an AVL tree. The program crashes when it enters the insert function. I am reading some file names from a text file and passing them to this insert_data function which then calls insert_node. These are my functions

```
void DataStructure::insert_data(char * &fileName, long int address)
{  
    this->root =  this->insert_node(this->root, fileName, address);
}


node * DataStructure::insert_node( node *t, char * &file_name, long int address)
    {
        if(t==NULL)
{
    t = new node;
    t->address = address;
    strcpy(t->buffer, file_name);
    t->height = 0;
    t->left = NULL;
    t->right = NULL;
}
else if(atoi(file_name) < atoi(t->buffer))
{
    t->left = insert_node(t->left, file_name, address);
    if(get_height(t->left) - get_height(t->right) == 2)
    {
        if(atoi(file_name) < atoi(t->left->buffer))
            t=SingleRotationLeft(t);
        else
            t=DoubleRotationLeft(t);
    }
}
else if( atoi(file_name) > atoi(t->buffer))
{
    t->right = insert_node(t->right, file_name, address);
    if(get_height(t->right) - get_height(t->left) == 2)
    {
        if(atoi(file_name) > atoi(t->right->buffer))
            t= SingleRotationRight(t);
        else
            t=DoubleRotationRight(t);
    }
}

t->height = max_height(get_height(t->left), get_height(t->right)) + 1;
return t;
}
```

and my construction function is

```
DataStructure::DataStructure(void)
{
    root = NULL;
}
```

Comment: `strcpy(t->buffer, file_name);` this seems wrong. What is the size of t->buffer?

Comment: How is `node` defined?  Specifically, is `buffer` a `char` array or just a pointer?

Comment: node is a structure
struct node{ char * buffer; long int address
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
strcpy(t->buffer, file_name);
```

is writing to an uninitialised pointer.  You need to allocate memory for `buffer`.  If you're on a Posix-compatible system, the easiest way to do this is by using `strdup`

```
t->buffer = strdup(file_name);
```

Otherwise, you need to allocate memory then copy separately

```
t->buffer = malloc(strlen(file_name)+1);
strcpy(t->buffer, file_name);
```

In either case, you'll need to `free(t->buffer)` when you free memory for each `node`